# Django turn url to image / views

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Hı, i have a model in my django code that stores urls of images but how am I going to write a view that displays them as images in a list?

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    photo = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    story = models.TextField(unique=True)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=datetime.datetime.now)
```

Comment: There are many ways of doing it but can you provide some context as to where the images are stored. If they are hosted on your domain or if they are external images.

Comment: Check out my answer, i just updated it

Comment: @elvie You should also consider using a [URLField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#urlfield) for the `photo` field.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a list of the object `Blog`, then you can do it in several cases. The first one is generic view `ListView`:

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from yourapp.models import Blog

class BlogListView(ListView):
    model = Blog
```

In that case your urls will looks like that:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from yourapp.views import BlogListView
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', BlogListView.as_view(), name='blog-list'),
]
```

and template:

```
{% blog in object_list %}
   <img src="{{blog.photo}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Here is link on [it](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)

the other way is creating request:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from yourapp.models import blog
def blogListView(request):
  blog_list = Blog.objects.all()
  return request(render, 'path/to/your/template.html', {'blog_list':blog_list})
```

In that case your url will look like this:

```
url(r'^$', views.blogListView, name='blog-list'),
```

Your template:

```
{% for blog in blog_list%}
   <img src="{{blog.photo}}">
{% endfor %}
```

**So you just have add `<img src="{{blog.photo}}">` in your template**